# find says "Hard link count is wrong"

Tags: unix, filesystems

I am trying to essentially find all files in my home directory which are greater than 1kb and make a .bak zip extension for the files. I am using this command `find $HOME -type f` just to display the files alone but I am getting the warning

```
find: WARNING: Hard link count is wrong for .../users/mburkhar:
this may be a bug in your filesystem driver. Automatically turning 
on find's -noleaf option. Earlier results may have failed to include
directories that should have been searched.
```

I have tried to do research about the -noleaf but I can't really find what I am looking for... What do I do about this problem?

Comment: You probably need to run `fsck` or its modern equivalent on your file system.  This might be automatic on a reboot, especially if you (carefully) crash your system.

Comment: To expand on Jonathan's comment, the error message you're getting is a pretty clear indication that your filesystem is (to some extent) corrupted.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the quick responses.